# sql - After ORDERed BY one field, then ORDER BY different fields

Tags: sql

Suppose there is a table with fields A, B, C

First I have sorted the rows with ORDER BY A
Then I want the rows with A=0 to be ORDERed BY B but the rows with A=1 to be ORDERed BY C

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible assuming that `B` and `C` have the same types:

```
order by A,
         (case when A = 0 then B
               when A = 1 then C
          end)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Works exactly the same as what I want!